# Last minute event tickets for London 2012 Olympic Games

Tags: london, events, sports-events, olympics

I know that tickets go on advance sale across the world in countries participating in the Olympics, each with their own quota. But this is for advance bookings. If one doesn't have firm plans and happens to be in London / England during the Olympic Games, is there any way to buy tickets at the venue itself (perhaps only for specific events) or only a week or two in advance?

Comment: You do know that the UK ticket allocations sold out via a lottery in which most people only got a fraction of what they applied for?

Comment: and yet, there are still football tickets at the locations in Scotland for sale.  Not all tickets are sold, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be box offices open outside events. Some events are selling slower than others. This is especially true of events outside London such as the football in Glasgow. You can see online at [www.tickets.london2012.com/](http://www.tickets.london2012.com/) what events are available. Buying online near the time will require you to collect the ticket at the box office outside the even. Simply take your photo ID and the card you used for payment or the booking confirmation email and you can receive the purchased tickets.

Additionally, some people may cancel there plans to attend the games. There is an official route on the [www.tickets.london2012.com](http://www.tickets.london2012.com/) website for reselling tickets at the original price only. So even some of the big events might have a few tickets on the day due to cancellations.

Personally, I've already got my tickets. They arrived in the post yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

From 11am UK time on Wednesday May 28, the final batch of tickets goes on sale.

[London 2012 Olympics: final batch of tickets to go on general release](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/olympics/9282318/London-2012-Olympics-final-batch-of-tickets-to-go-on-general-release.html)

> Organisers have confirmed that there is still a good availability for
>   a range of sports including archery, badminton, basketball, beach
>   volleyball, diving, handball and hockey.
>
> There are also some tickets for highly sought-after events including
>   gymnastics, both artistic and trampoline.
>
> There are very few available tickets for medal events, with only
>   higher priced tickets available for the majority of the medal events.

It also seems likely that some events will not be fully sold out - especially events not as high-profile in Europe and the UK - archery, handball and more.

Finally if you're really desperate to see *anything*, events like the marathon are open and free to viewers along the majority of the route :)

**EDIT**

I suspect there's also a black market of sorts for tickets, but I wouldn't recommend going down that route.

Comment: What about authorised reselling of tickets?

Comment: it is illegal to sell tickets on the black market I believe the fine is 20k. However if you know someone with a spare ticket you can reimburse them the face value for the ticket so long as you go with them.

Comment: @Stuart - you could turn that comment into an answer really - it's another valid way to get last minute tickets.